# Relay Sometimes Not Switching

Tags: arduino, relay

I have a question about relays used by an arduino.
I know how to wire them and they work fine for the most of the time.

But sometimes the relays doesn't correctly switch on or off.
I can clearly see that the LED on the relay is in the correct state.
I can also hear a faint "click" sound. But the relay is not really switching.

Even funnier, then I physically hit/punch the relay with i.e. screwdriver it starts to switch to the desired state...

Usually the problems start when the arduino is running for a few days.

I have also tried completely different relays and have the same issue with them.

**Does anybody know what can cause such issues?**

Edit:

- I am using an SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay with an Arduino Nano.
- I have also tried different arduino compatible relays. Same issue.
- I use it to power a light which uses ~250W.
- Usually powering off works fine. But powering on needs a "physical hit" on the box of the relay.

I will try to measure the output tomorrow 7 o'clock when the relay is supposed to switch on again (just before I hit the relay box to force it to switch on)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us about the load you are switching, and the specifications of the relay? It is possible for relays to undergo mechanical degradation if they are operated inappropriately, which can manifest in ways such as contacts that fail to connect or disconnect.

Comment: Relays need at least 2/3 of their rated voltage to switch and their rated voltage to switch fast. Can you measure anything?

Comment: Are you controlling the relays directly with the output pins of the arduino? They can only handle up to 20mA. Your relay may need more current than that to safely switch. Check the datasheet and maybe use a transitor in between to supply your relay with enough power.

Comment: This question is missing crucial information to be answerable. The LED is likely not related to the actual relay state, so it doesn't prove or disprove anything. Measure the voltage across the coil and compare it to what the spec says.

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your questions guys. I make a little schematic today of my circuit.

Comment: You stated that "the relay is not really switching" but then you fail to describe how you even know that. If you don't tell us, we are left to guess, which will lead to wrong answers or no answers, and wasted time. Please show your measurements. Preferably output from an oscilloscope, but even a multimeter will give a better understanding. You also provided a simplified fritzing diagram. While I understand you may be new to this, those diagrams create problems. You should strive to create a traditional schematic.Your diagram doesn't even label the 3 control pins on the relay. Difficult to help

Comment: @Bort Got you. Sorry for the confusion. I first try now to power the relay with external 5v as Electric_90 suggested. If that doesn't work I am going to clarify everything and make a traditional schematic and measurements.

Comment: @gentooboy - There is a free schematic editor available here when you post an answer, but I personally recommend https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html. I think you'll like it, and learn a lot from it!

Comment: @Bort Thank you a lot! I will use that to make my future schematics. Sorry again for the confusion. I can understand that I left a lot of room open for guesswork.

Comment: @gentooboy - No worries. The fact that you are willing to learn from your mistakes and correct them is what really matters. Note that users here, including I, can come off as abrasive at times. It's because of the huge number of people that walk in and drop homework or hobby questions with little or no effort or context and then demand help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the way the relay is being powered. The voltage regulator on Arduino is not sufficient enough to provide the needed amperage for switching the relay properly and thus even if the led lights up the relay contacts are not touching with enough force.

I would recommend you to use an external 5V source for powering the relay. Or if you are supplying your Arduino Nano with 5V then connect the relay's VCC to VIN of Arduino.

Also, do keep in mind that if the relay is not supplied with proper power, it can lead to internal sparking of switching contacts which can damage the relay.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your insight.
I will try to power the relay externally and see if this fixes the issue!

Comment: After using an external 5V power supply for the relay it seems to work. I will test it for a few weeks, but for now I think this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you are supplying enough voltage to the relay. If you're using one of those boards with a built in driver, you'll want to measure right across the coil terminals.

If the relay is getting enough voltage, then the contacts are probably the issue, and you should get a new relay.

Comment: I have tried completely different relays. But for some reason I have the same issue. I will try to measure the voltage tomorrow when the relay is supposed to switch on again.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue with a RPi powering the same relay. I was using the 3.3V output to power the relay, same as the detection - this is the default with the jumper is in place. Changed it to use the 5V output and it now switches fine.